# Tkinter add icon image (correctly declaring in python?)

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

[image]I am wanting add my own custom ico image with Tkinter.

Below works:

```
root = tk.Tk()
root.iconbitmap("C:\\Users\\Hoxton\\Pictures\\Saved Pictures\\download_U8F_icon.ico")
```

However, when I try to integrate this with my script it does not read the image.     I believe the answer is as simple as not declaring something.  But I am going around in circles.  Can anyone help me to get this icon image working?

```
import tkinter as tk

import tkinter as tk
import sys
class MyDialog:
    import tkinter as tk



    import tkinter

    def __init__(self, parent):
        top = self.top = tk.Toplevel(parent)
        top.iconbitmap("C:\\Users\\Hoxton\\Pictures\\Saved Pictures\\download_U8F_icon.ico")
        self.myLabel = tk.Label(top, text='Enter the Amount of Emails you would like to create')
        self.myLabel.pack()


        self.myEntryBox = tk.Entry(top)
        self.myEntryBox.pack()
        self.mySubmitButton = tk.Button(top, text='Submit', command=self.send)
        self.mySubmitButton.pack()


    def send(self):
        self.username = self.myEntryBox.get()
        self.top.destroy()

from selenium import webdriver
def onClick():
    inputDialog = MyDialog(root)
    root.wait_window(inputDialog.top)
    root.iconbitmap("C:\\Users\\Hoxton\\Pictures\\Saved Pictures\\download_U8F_icon.ico")
    print('Emails Created: ', inputDialog.username)
    print(inputDialog.username)
    x = int(inputDialog.username)
    for _ in range(x):
        driver = webdriver.Chrome()
        driver.set_window_size(1024, 600)
        #sys.exit()


    root.destroy()




root = tk.Tk()
mainLabel = tk.Label(root, text='How many Emails do you want to create?')
mainLabel.pack()

mainButton = tk.Button(root, text='Custom Amount', command=onClick)
mainButton.pack()

root.mainloop()
print('Username: ')
```

Comment: What size is the .ico?

Comment: @Nae I think I see the issue. Hmm how to fix it though.  SO it changes icon of the message box when you click Custom amount but not other message box.  See image above

Comment: @Nae Got it working :D

Comment: Well you could post the answer.

Comment: @Nae it's so beautiful :').  Haha, will do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a case of not declaring things as I suspected.  Be mindful of how you declare:

```
root = tk.Tk()
mainLabel = tk.Label(root, text='How many Emails do you want to create?')
root.iconbitmap("C:\\Users\\Hoxton\\Pictures\\Saved Pictures\\download_U8F_icon.ico")
mainLabel.pack()
```

As well as:

```
def __init__(self, parent):
    top = self.top = tk.Toplevel(parent)
    top.iconbitmap("C:\\Users\\Hoxton\\Pictures\\Saved Pictures\\download_U8F_icon.ico")
    self.myLabel = tk.Label(top, text='Enter the Amount of Emails you would like to create')
    self.myLabel.pack()
```